# Parse date format in laravel carbon

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am tryin to parse date format using laravel carbon. Here I tried

```
dd(Carbon::parse('2021-10-12T09:20:27:915 GMT+0600')->format('Y-m-d h:i:s'));
```

It shows DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2021-10-12T09:20:27:915 GMT+0600) at position 19 (:): Unexpected

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where/how are you getting the date in this format?

Answer (score 0):

in the above code, you have mentioned, You are using **DateTime** with Locale.

```
 /**
     * Create a carbon instance from a string.
     *
     * This is an alias for the constructor that allows better fluent syntax
     * as it allows you to do Carbon::parse('Monday next week')->fn() rather
     * than (new Carbon('Monday next week'))->fn().
     *
     * @param string|DateTimeInterface|null $time
     * @param DateTimeZone|string|null      $tz
     *
     * @throws InvalidFormatException
     *
     * @return static
     */
    public static function parse($time = null, $tz = null)
    {
        $function = static::$parseFunction;

        if (!$function) {
            return static::rawParse($time, $tz);
        }

        if (\is_string($function) && method_exists(static::class, $function)) {
            $function = [static::class, $function];
        }

        return $function(...\func_get_args());
    }
```

instead of using the parse , you can use

```
    public static function parseFromLocale($time, $locale = null, $tz = null)
```

than you will be able to parse your time very easily.